# Returning elements in a list also found in another list

Tags: python, performance

I'm trying to write a short function which takes a list (`a`) and returns another list which only contains the elements (`x`) such that `-x` is also in `a`. I've done that, and it works, but it runs really slowly. I know why it does, and I know the second `for` loop is unnecessary, but I don't know how to fix it without breaking the function.

```
def negated(a):
    mark = set()
    add_mark = mark.add
    b = []
    c = []
    for i in a:
        if i not in mark and not add_mark(i):
            b.append(i)
    for i in b:
        if -i in b:
            c.append(i)
    return c
```

Comment: How big are your lists?  How fast is this code?  Can you provide some more details?

Comment: Add the whole of `a` to your set, then do all of your membership checks against that.  Set lookups are O(1) time.

Comment: One thing you could do is split the list into positive and negative number lists beforehand, and iterate through only one of them, checking whether the corresponding value is present in the other list.

Comment: This is a two-liner if you just build the set directly from the list.  `mark = set(a); return [x for x in a if -x in mark]`.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper That is concise, but the OP is looking for efficiency. With every iteration in that comprehension, you are wasting time checking against values of the same sign as x, and you are also performing twice as many searches as is necessary.

Comment: Are you answering the same assignment that Nolan Hodge had [a few hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279449/return-values-in-list-that-also-have-a-negated-value/19279505#19279505)?

Comment: @Asad: If you just change the `for x in a` to `for x in mark`, Peter DeGlopper's answer is likely as fast as possible. (That assumes that order doesn't matter, and that there are no duplicates or they don't matter, but that was true for the near-identical question I linked to).

Comment: And yeah, it looks that way Abarnert. Didnt see it in the search

Comment: @abarnert For an input set `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -3]`, it is more efficient to separate the negatives from the positives in bulk, so that when checking for the presence of any negative, you don't have to compare against `1,2,3,4,5` on every iteration.

Comment: @Asad: A lookup against a set of size N is just as fast as against a set of size N/2.

Comment: @abarnert But it isn't 1 lookup. It is N lookups, since you're going through the entire list.

Comment: @Asad - correct on the twice as many comparisons - I consider that acceptable in order to get the syntax benefits of a comprehension - but I'm not sure what you mean about 'checking against values of the same sign as x'. I doubt that the speed gains of having two different half-sized sets to check for membership in outweigh the time needed to split the list in two to construct the sets. I'd also want to profile the comprehension against an explicit for loop that avoids the extra comparisons - I suspect the comprehension is implemented faster even if it's technically doing more work.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I'll get back to you with a perf on that.

Comment: @Asad: Well, you're saving N/2 O(1) lookups by doing an extra N O(1) lookups…

Comment: What is the correct output if the input is `[-1, -1, 1]`?

Comment: @Alex: I just realized we spent an hour arguing about trivial tweaks without anyone ever pointing out the basic flaw in your original version, which is what you asked for… I'll edit my answer to explain that.

Answer (score 5):

First, let's get this out of the way:

The reason the OP version is slow is that, to decide whether to insert elements into `c`, it checks each one of them against `b`—a list, rather than a set. That means it's quadratic when it could be linear.

You could fix that by making another set, call it `mark2 = set(b)`, then using `if -i in mark2` instead of `if -i in b`.

That means your code is no longer quadratic, it's linear. Which is probably all you cared about.

However, it's looping twice as much as it needs to, and it's doing all of the looping in Python rather than finding ways to push it into C. That `add_mark = mark.add` optimization implies that you might be looking for more such tricks, and you should be able to cut the time to about a third.

But just fixing that isn't good enough once you get the community going, so a number of variations have been suggested both here and on [a previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279449/return-values-in-list-that-also-have-a-negated-value/19279505#19279505). Which one is actually 
fastest?

---

Instead of just guessing, let's actually write and test some implementations and see. Of course for real answers we need your real data, but I'll make up some data, and that should be enough to show you how to do it yourself.

```
# my answer on the earlier question, and my comment above
def negated_0(a):
    a = set(a)
    return [i for i in a if -i in a]

# Peter DeGlopper's comment, and hcwhsa's on the earlier question
def negated_1(a):
    s = set(a)
    return [i for i in a if -i in s]

# one suggestion I made on the earlier question
def negated_2(a):
    return set(a) & {-i for i in a}

# another suggestion I thought my be a little faster but not worth it
def negated_3(a):
    return {-i for i in a}.intersection(a)

# a possibly-improved version of #3 that I just thought of
def negated_4(a):
    a = set(a)
    return a & {-i for i in a}

# kojiro's posted answer
def negated_kojiro(a):
    '''Take a list a and returns another list which only contains the elements x such that -x is also in a'''
    neg, pos = set(), set()
    for i in a:
        if i < 0:
            neg.add(-1*i)
        else:
            pos.add(i)
    return [i for i in a if abs(i) in pos & neg]

import timeit
import random

a = [random.randint(-10000,10000) for _ in range(1000)]
for func in dir(sys.modules('__main__')):
    if func.startswith('negated_'):
        f = getattr(sys.modules('__main__'), func)
        print('{}: {}'.format(func, timeit.timeit(lambda: f(a), number=10000))
```

Here's the output on one laptop with Apple's Python 2.7.2:

```
negated_0: 1.50614500046
negated_1: 1.45001101494
negated_2: 1.79172492027
negated_3: 1.29876303673
negated_4: 1.92844605446
negated_kojiro: 84.5585548878
```

… and with a default-configured local build of Python 3.4 trunk:

```
negated_0: 1.5246370710083283
negated_1: 1.420855167991249
negated_2: 1.7558801580162253
negated_3: 1.297387560014613
negated_4: 1.8665565319824964
negated_kojiro: 72.18082603899529
```

… and with PyPy 2.1.0/2.7.3:

```
negated_0: 0.595048904419
negated_1: 0.405268907547
negated_2: 0.815263032913
negated_3: 0.878368139267
negated_4: 0.910092115402
negated_kojiro: 49.3969540596
```

---

Comparing the fixed version of the OP's implementation:

```
negated_op: 4.76454496384
negated_op: 3.3227077620103955
negated_op: 0.87509393692
```

(The original, unfixed version took over 79 seconds before I killed it in 2.7.2.)

We've improved it by 3x in CPython 2.7.2, but only 2x in the other implementations. Not quite what I'd hoped, but not bad.

---

It looks like `negated_3` actually *is* a decent-sized win over the obvious implementation, but nothing else is. (And #4 actually makes things worse.)

Wrapping #2-#4 in `list(…)` so they return the same type as the others shows virtually no difference:

```
negated_0: 1.54194092751
negated_1: 1.44428801537
negated_2: 1.78255009651
negated_3: 1.29559803009
negated_4: 1.90534591675
```

---

Fixing the most serious problem with kojiro's answer, by evaluating `pos & neg` once outside the listcomp instead of for each element, gives me:

```
negated_kojiro_fix: 2.11841907501
negated_kojiro_fix: 3.84713697433
negated_kojiro_1: 0.739408969879
```

So, it's still significantly slower than `negated_1` (which, like it, preserves duplicates and order) everywhere. Why?

It *could* be that it's doing twice as much setup work and not getting a comparable amount of savings in the actual comprehension. It may be simpler work, but still, adding O(N) loops in Python to speed up an O(N) list comprehension might be costly.

But there's also the fact that the listcomp filter is more complicated: `abs(i) in mark` instead of the `-i in mark`. So, if we could make it even simpler, would that make the listcomp even faster? Just keep the *negated* set around, and do `i in mark`. Which means you can replace the listcomp with a `filter` by using `mark.__contains__` as the argument:

```
def negated_3b(a):
    mark = {-i for i in a}
    return filter(mark.__contains__, a)
```

(For Python 3, you have to make that `list(filter(…))` of course, or it'll return almost instantly, having built an iterable but not iterated it.)

The results with the same three Python implementations are:

```
negated_3b: 1.39607014656
negated_3b: 1.8215457699843682
negated_3b: 0.51006603241
```

So… it beats all of the other order-and-dups-preserving methods in 2.x, CPython or PyPy, but not the set-returning `negated_3` (which is obvious, when you think about it).

However, it's *slower* in 3.x. Maybe that's just because of the necessity of calling `list`? If you don't actually *need* a list, let's see how long it takes to iterate it, by just feeding the iterator into `deque(maxlen=0)`:

```
negated_3b: 1.6808519120211713
```

Better, but still not as good as `negated_1` in Python 3. Maybe it's just that 3.x's `filter` hasn't been improved since the original version was written as 2.x's `itertools.ifilter`, but listcomps have been improved multiple times over the years?

---

So, conclusions—if your data are very similar to mine (which is very unlikely!):

- Unless this is such a bottleneck in your code that a few microseconds one way or the other actually make a difference, use whichever one is most readable.
- If you don't need to preserve order and duplicates, use `negated_3`.
- If you're using Python 2.x, use `negated_3b`.
- Otherwise, use `negated_1`.

Comment: I contend that answers that eliminate duplicate values or return a non-list are illegitimate.

Comment: @kojiro: On what basis? A previous user with exactly the same assignment said there were no duplicate values; this user hasn't said otherwise. Meanwhile, tossing on a `list(…)` isn't going to make up the 50x slowdown, but I'll do it if you insist.

Comment: It also matters whether or not maintaining order is required. I think all the ones with reasonable performance except `negated_1` don't necessarily maintain order even if you put a `list()` around them.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: Please see [the original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279449/return-values-in-list-that-also-have-a-negated-value/19279505#19279505), where the OP's desired output is not in the same order as the original input. So, I doubt maintaining order is important. (If so, then we have to figure out _what_ order is important, because it's not the _input_ order, which is what `negated_1` maintains…)

Comment: @abarnert - thanks for the link. The OP for this question didn't specify. I generally assume that when the input and output are stated to be lists, the output should maintain the input order, but it's certainly not specified one way or the other here.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: Yeah, also note that the other OP's own attempt to solve it started by converting the list to a set. Of course it's possible that the other OP didn't understand the assignment, and this one does…

Comment: @abarnert just on the basis that (no offense to OP) I think that if you can eliminate repetition and order the problem isn't interesting anymore. Sets are great, but they make some problems too easy. :P

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of clarity, here is a solution that keeps duplicates and retains the original order of elements in `a`.

```
def negated_stable(a):
    '''Take a list a and returns another list which only contains the elements x such that -x is also in a'''
    b = set(a)
    return [i for i in a if -i in b]
```

This was my original solution, which is a little slower than other solutions here, but I'll keep it around for posterity.

```
def negated_posterity(a):
    '''Take a list a and returns another list which only contains the elements x such that -x is also in a'''
    neg, pos = set(), set()
    for i in a:
        if i < 0:
            neg.add(-1*i)
        else:
            pos.add(i)
    mark = pos & neg
    return [i for i in a if abs(i) in mark]
```

If you can sacrifice order and/or duplication this becomes a trivial problem, as demonstrated by the five or so `set` solutions in abarnert's answer.

Comment: This takes almost two orders of magnitude longer than Peter DeGlopper's one-liner (aka hcwhsa's answer on the earlier question).

Comment: I think you want `return list(pos & neg)`

Comment: @BiRico I thought of that, but OP may not want to eliminate dupes.

Comment: The first problem with this solution is that it's evaluating `pos&neg` N times instead of once outside the loop. Fix that, and it becomes competitive with the others. But still not as fast, because making a set all at once, and a negated set with a comprehension, is so much faster than looping explicitly in Python that it swamps the cost of the repeated elements that you're trying to save.

Comment: @abarnert I wondered if that was it. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: I just realized another cost of this partitioning: because you throw out the useless negative numbers that the other solution keeps, you have to do `abs(i)` instead of `-i`. Which makes me wonder… what if we just kept the negated set around (`mark = {-i for i in a}`) and then you could do `[i for i in a if i in mark]`, or possibly even bind `mark.__contains__` to a local variable? I'll test those…